# How to display text received from a web api in angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angular, cors

I have an Asp.Net Core web api method that returns a string.

```c#
   [Route("GetString")]
        public string GetString()
        {
            return "String from <b> Web </b> API";
        }
```

The URL works fine in a browser, however, when I run it from an angular 2 app

```js
getDialog(){  
      this.result = this.http.get(this._stringUrl1).forEach((response) => response.text); 
      console.log(this.result); 
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49596/Content/GetString. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I get the same response if I call a web api method that returns an HttpResponseMessage.

```
 [Route("GetHttpResponseMessage")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetString2()
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent("HttpResponseMessage from Web API 2", Encoding.UTF8, "Text/txt");
            return response;

        }
```

This is my first Angular app so I am not sure if my angular2 code is correct or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your Angular code; you need to implement CORS handling on the API side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in asp.net web api (4.5), i found out that you have to add the permission in two places:
1) at startup (webapiconfig.cs)

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
                origins: "*",
                headers: "*",
                methods: "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

2) at the controller level (pocoController.cs)

```
namespace BiGPOCO.API.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:3000", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class PocoController : ApiController
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This typical happens when your client and server are not running on the same domain.

You can do this enable CORS on your API server since you are using C# you do do this inside of your web.config *only for development*. Where 3000 is your client port

`<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000" />
 </customHeaders>`

Or there is a google chrome plugin that enables this as well. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en

You can easily toggle this on and off at your leisure. There are other methods as well as in modifying your request header etc...

These are just simpler.